# Why can I not access forms' errors attributes in django template?

Tags: django, forms, error-handling

The code below shows my template, views, and forms code. I would like to display the errors generated by the .is_valid() functions called in views.py when the form html is re-rendered.  The problem is that I cannot even access the errors within the incident_form and incident_formset, let alone display them. Neither incident_form.errors, incident_formset.errors, nor

```
{% for field in incident_form %}
  {% for error in field.errors %}
    <p> {{ error }} </p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

allow me to view the errors generated by the .is_valid method. Strangely enough, the crispy app returns to the invalid form with the first invalid field highlighted and ready to accept input from the user. Also, when the date field is filled out incorrectly, the form will *sometimes* display an error like "Invalid date field". However, no required fields which are submitted without data show "Required" errors. Help is much appreciated.

Snippet of new_incident.html:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    {% crispy incident_form %}
    <input type="button" id="delete_field_data" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Delete Field Incident Data">

    <div id="form_set_class">
        {{ incident_formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in incident_formset %}
            {{form.non_field_errors}}
            {{form.errors}}
            {% crispy form %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    [...]
```

Snippet of forms.py:

```
class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IncidentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout( [<edited_out_for_this_post] )
        self.helper.form_id = "incident_form"

class PartDeficiencyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PartDeficiency
        fields = "__all__"

DeficiencyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=PartDeficiency, form=PartDeficiencyForm, exclude=None, extra=0, max_num=20, can_delete=True)
```

Snippet of views.py:

```
def new_incident(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        incident_form = IncidentForm(request.POST)
        deficiency_formset = DeficiencyFormSet(request.POST)

        if incident_form.is_valid() and deficiency_formset.is_valid():
            incident_form.save()
            deficiency_formset.save()
            return redirect('quality_dept:home')

        else:
            dict = {'incident_form': incident_form, 'incident_formset': deficiency_formset}
            return render(request, 'incidents/new_incident.html', dict)

    else:
        incident_form = IncidentForm()
        formset_data = { 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '0',
                     'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
                     'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '20'}
        def_formset = DeficiencyFormSet(formset_data)
        dict = {'incident_form': incident_form, 'incident_formset': def_formset}
        return render(request, 'incidents/new_incident.html', dict)
```

Comment: within your context you've called it `incident_form` but within the template you're using `form`

Comment: in my template "form" refers to the individual forms in the named formset - see the "for" control statement. my incident_form is rendered by the crispy tag {% crispy incident_form %}